# could not convert string to float: 'Product_0332'

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

```
   Product_Code    Warehouse   Product_Category   Date       Order_Demand

0  Product_0332    Whse_J     Category_021        05-01-17   1
1  Product_1909    Whse_J     Category_019        29-12-16   1
```

i can apply. like,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Product_Code'] = df['Product_Code'].astype(float)
```

but did not convert string to float..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the numeric part such as `0332` and `1909`, then just apply :

```
df['Product_Code'] = df['Product_Code'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

or also want to convert to a numeric format such as float with the results as `332` and `1909`, then add `astype('float')` to the end of the expression also :

```
df['Product_Code'] = df['Product_Code'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype('float')
```

*you can apply arthmetic operations to `df['Product_Code']` in this second case.*